# Can I force the event I create in my online Google Calender to 'push' or 'sync' to phone?

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I've created a Google script to create an event in my Google Calendar. What I want to happen is to be reminded about that event on my device (Andriod phone). However, as far as I can tell the local phone calendar does not auto sync, unless it's opened. So, if I don't open the calendar app on my phone I dont get the reminder.
If I do open the app, I see the event sync, and I then subsequently get a reminder.
Is there a way I can therefore force the event to be synced with my device calendar - to somehow push it to that device

Regards

Steve

I tried to set a routine on the phone to open the calendar - but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: Hi and welcome. _What I want to happen is to be reminded about that event on my device_ You can set any number of notifications and/or emails within Calendar. Is this what you mean by reminders?

Comment: Hi. I have created the Event in my calender via the GoogleScript. The event has a reminder. The problem is that the reminder does not pop up on my phone. I believe this is because the Event is not 'pushed' to the phone, and so the phone does not even know about the event until i open up the calendar app (at which point it is synced).

Comment: Hmm. Event _are_ notified on my iPhone (Messages). Have you read and applied this guide [Modify Google Calendar notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)? I note one of the troubleshooting items - "Not getting notifications" - "Make sure sync works properly. [Fix sync problems with the Google Calendar app](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6261951)."

Comment: Hi, and Thanks. Yep, had already looked at both of them. If I create an event centrally via Script, and then go into the calander on the phone, it immediately syncs - and at the correct time it notifies me. However, if I create an event central, but i do NOT go into the calander, it does NOT notifiy me. My belief is becuase it has not been synced. However, I cant prove that, becuasde the moment i go into the calander on the phone then it syncs !

Comment: Steve, what are default notifications? Actually, what happens if you just re-create/confirm the notifications in your script. They should be triggered automatically in the cloud; least ways that's what happens with my iPhone notifications.